# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

Tags: eclipse, spring, transactionmanager

I'm developping an application using spring and hibernate.

When I run my application I get this error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
```

In my context application file I have this :

```
<bean id="tansactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

I googled about the problem and I found a solution that I have to change this line :

```
<bean id="tansactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
```

By :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
```

But I got another problem :

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Do you use jpa with hibernate? if you use jpa you have to change the sessionFactory to entityManagerFactory.

Comment: and reason for your first approach failing is just because of typo in the bean ID.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your annotation "tansactionManager" is missing and 'r', "transactionManager". I made the correction and it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using session factory, so this should work

```
<bean id="tansactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

but if you want to use JPA  EntityManager, so you need

```
    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
             <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Please refer to [migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1](http://spring.io/blog/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1) it contains nice example for the required configurations